# Add new column to sqlite in app new version (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite

I am doing iOS app. I have version 1.0 in Appstore. In that app we have integrated sqlite database for the local data backup. For that i created table.

Now i  am going to update it to 1.1 versions and adding new column in that table. But, after build my app in xcode my app was crashed due to while launching time i am fetching the data from sqlite table. so, i have already old version which does not contains new column in database build in my device. After uninstall that old one, i again build new code, then its worked fine.

If i upload this new pack to app store, i am sure it will crash after updated the app because they have already installed old version of my app.

its not possible to uninstall app to everybody device.

How can i solve this issue, so far i have never worked this type scenario.

I have checked google, but very less examples i found. 
There, they said we need to check column exists or not, if not exist add new column. But i am confusion how to do this task. Any example for clear understand!

Comment: finally i fixed this issue!!! by following code, i hope this will help somebody in coming days!!

Comment: http://pastie.org/private/91umc6m62pi6rqsyzrya